# Big theta run time of string concatenation?

Tags: java, time, concatenation, big-o, biginteger

I have an assignment to create my own implementation of a class to handle integers of unlimited size, and then to compare my implementation's runtime to that of Java's BigInteger. When I measured and graphed the runtime of my add function it was a parabola, implying a big theta running time of Ө(n^2). I have no nested loops so I expected it to be Ө(n) and cannot figure out why it isn't. I suspect it might be that I use

```
string += integer
```

in my add method inside a loop. I am not quite sure how that operation is implemented, is it a runtime of Ө(n)? If not, can anyone spot why my code isn't Ө(n)?

Here is my add method and the constructor it calls.

```
 public HugeInteger(String val) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    String temp = "";
    boolean leading = true;

    //check valid input
    for(int i=0; i<val.length(); i++){
        if(val.charAt(i) < '0' || val.charAt(i) > '9') //checks if each digit is a number from 0 to 9
            if(i!=0 || val.charAt(i) != '-') //doesn't throw if the digit is a '-' at the first character of string
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input string must be a number");
    }

    //remove leading zeros

    for(int i=0; i<val.length(); i++){
        if(!leading || val.charAt(i) != '0')
            temp += val.charAt(i);
        if(val.charAt(i) > '0' && val.charAt(i) <= '9') //reached first non-zero digit
            leading = false;
    }
    if(temp == "") //this happens when the input was just a string of zeros
        temp = "0";

    val = temp;

    if(val.charAt(0) != '-'){ //no negative sign
        digits = new int[val.length()];

        for(int i=0; i<val.length(); i++){
            digits[i] = (int)(val.charAt(val.length()-1-i) - 48); //in ASCII the char '0' == 48
        }
        negative = false;
    }
    else{
        digits = new int[val.length() - 1];

        for(int i=1; i<val.length(); i++){ //for loop starts after the '-' sign
            digits[i-1] = (int)(val.charAt(val.length()-i) - 48); //in ASCII the char '0' == 48
        }
        negative = true;
    }
}



public HugeInteger add(HugeInteger h){
    int carry = 0;
    int size = digits.length>h.digits.length?digits.length:h.digits.length; //choose larger # of digits
    String sum = "";
    String sumFlipped = "";
    int bigger = 0;
    boolean swapped = false;
    int temp;
    int sign = 1;
    int hsign = 1;

    //assign sign based on negative or not
    if(negative && !h.negative)
        sign = -1;
    if(!negative && h.negative)
        hsign = -1;

    //compare magnitudes. 1 means this is biger and -1 means h is bigger
    if(digits.length>h.digits.length)
        bigger = 1;
    else if(digits.length<h.digits.length)
        bigger = -1;
    else{ //same length
        for(int i=0; i<digits.length; i++){ //both digits arrays are same length

            if(digits[digits.length-1-i] > h.digits[h.digits.length-1-i]){
                bigger = 1;
                break;
            }
            if(digits[digits.length-1-i] < h.digits[h.digits.length-1-i]){
                bigger = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //positive number must be bigger than negative number for long subtraction
    //if not, swap signs
    if(bigger == 1 && negative && !h.negative){ //this is bigger and negative
        swapped = true;
        sign *= -1;
        hsign *= -1;  
    }

    if(bigger == -1 && !negative && h.negative){ //h is bigger and negative
        swapped = true;
        sign *= -1;
        hsign *= -1;  
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(i>=digits.length)
            temp = h.digits[i]*hsign + carry;
        else if(i>=h.digits.length)
            temp = digits[i]*sign + carry;
        else
            temp = digits[i]*sign + h.digits[i]*hsign + carry;

        if(temp>9){ //adds the digit to the string, then increments carry which is used in next iteration
            temp -= 10;
            sum += temp;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else if(temp<0){
            temp += 10;
            carry = -1;
            sum += temp;
        }
        else{
            sum += temp;
            carry = 0;
        }
    }

    if(carry == 1)
        sum += 1;

    if(negative && h.negative || swapped)
        sum += '-';

    //flip string around
    for(int i=0; i < sum.length(); i++){
        sumFlipped += sum.charAt(sum.length() - 1 - i);
    }

    HugeInteger sumHugeInteger = new HugeInteger(sumFlipped);

    return sumHugeInteger;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it's O(n). Can you show how you are measuring your running time and what the average size of your input is?

Comment: String += char is O(n) in the length of the string, which makes the whole loop O(n^2).   Use a StringBuilder instead.